# 4,5,6... dimensional data on 3D plot?

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

So the question is as simple as:

How can you visually represent some simple numeric data of more than three dimensions on a single 3D plot?

My guess is to add colour to the point or make point bigger or smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many answers to the question, but the "best" answer is going to depend on the context of the data. Does the data represent measurements from the natural world? Stock market data? Medical data? The results of sociological surveys?

A number of authors have written on the subject and presented different techniques. If you haven't already read **The Quantitative Display of Visual Information** by Tufte, then I'd recommend that for a start. If you intend to produce graphics of any kind that others will read, then Tufte will help you make better graphics. In my opinion you will not find instruction of similar quality by hunting for articles online.

There are textbooks on information visualization that present specific techniques for the display of multivariate data, but that it takes a textbook just to present a survey of techniques indicates how many different techniques there are.

Yes, color can be used to to represent one of the dimensions, BUT there are a number of limitations:

- Some readers/users are color-blind.
- The number of distinct colors you need may exceed the number that people can easily distinguish. (For example, is the red dot at the lower left slightly darker than the red dot at top right?)
- Using too many hues can be confusing. If you want color to represent a numeric scale from low to high, or from negative to positive, then you might be able to use a two-color transition. For example, relative temperature changes can be displayed as transitions from deep blue (cold) to white (nominal temperature) to deep red (hot). But "rainbow" and ROYGBIV color schemes tend to confuse and look ugly.
- If points are densely plotted, neighboring points may be hard to distinguish.
- ...

If one of the dimensions has a very limited range of values, then shapes can be used to indicate variable values. You could use different shapes such as diamond, triangle, circle, square, etc., or you could show a limited number of values in the dimensions of the shape, such as a flat oval for a low value and a perfectly round circle for a high or optimal value. However, if the reader has to keep referring to a key to see what each shape represents, then shapes likely aren't a good fit for your particular problem.

Using data point size to represent a variable can be especially difficult. If the display is "3D", and if points are displayed at different depths, then it could be easy to confuse a small point close up with a larger point farther away. Size of a data "point" (if it's just a point) can be useful in 2D graphs precisely because of the lack of a third dimension.

One of the more interesting and unusual techniques I've seen is "dust and magnets" visualization, which lends itself well to intuitive exploration of certain kinds of multivariate data:
http://www.cc.gatech.edu/gvu/ii/dnm/

If you spend a bit of time googling "multivariate data plot," "multivariate data graph," and the like, you'll find quite a few avenues to explore.